# How can I and if can I avoid multiple if statements to make my code less space, memory and time consuming? Is there any way?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

My code is quite complex and involves triangle analysis. The code is set up for user to enter values of each single triangle's side and base of that values the code determines at first whether whether the triangle is possible with those sides' values if and calculates at thereafter whether the triangle is acute, obtuse or right triangle, and also whether is acute acute isosceles, obtuse isosceles or equilateral?! Thereafter it calculates the triangle's perimeter and area! The code contains 73 lines and it seems to me quite cumbersome, time and space consuming. Is it possible to achieve the same goal with fewer lines of code to rationalize code writing process?!

The code:

```
var flag = false;
while(!flag){
    var a = prompt('Enter the first- the longest edge of the triangle(a number>=0):', a);
    a1 = Number(a);
    var b = prompt('Enter the second longest edge of the triangle(a number>=0):', b);
    b1 =Number(b);
    var c = prompt('Enter the third longest(the shortest) edge of the triangle(a number>=0):',    c);
    c1 = Number(c);
    if((a1<=0)||(b1<=0)||(c1<=0)||(typeof a==='undefined')||(typeof b==='undefined')||(typeof c==='undefined')){
    alert('Invalid date!Each of the data entered has to be a number greater than or equal to 0!');
    continue;
}else if((a1>=b1+c1)||(b1>=a1+c1)||(c1>=a1+b1)){
    alert('It is not a triangle! Each edge can not be greater than the sum of remaining two!');
    flag =false;
}else{
    alert('OK! You can move on with process!');
    break;
}
```

}

```
let h1 = Math.max(a1, b1, c1);
h2 = Number(h1);
alert('The highest edge is: '+h2);
if((((a1**2)<(b1**2)+(c1**2))&&(a1===b1)&&(b1===c1)&&(a1===c1))){ 
    alert('The triangle is equilateral!');
}else if((h2 === a1)&&((a1**2)>(b1**2)+(c1**2))&&(b1===c1)){
    alert('The triangle is obtuse and isosceles!');
}else if((h2 === a1)&&((a1**2)>(b1**2)+(c1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is obtuse!');
}else if((h2===a1)&&((a1**2) === (b1**2)+(c1**2))&&(b1===c1)){
    alert('The triangle is right and isosceles!');
}else if((h2===a1)&&((a1**2) === (b1**2)+(c1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is right!');
}else if((h2===a1)&&((a1**2)<((b1**2)+(c1**2))&&((a1===b1)||(b1===c1)||(a1===c1)))){
    alert('The triangle is acute and isosceles!');
}else if((h2===a1)&&((a1**2)<(b1**2)+(c1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is acute!');
}else if((h2=== b1)&&((b1**2)===(a1**2)+(c1**2))&&(a1===c1)){
    alert('The triangle is right and isosceles!');
}else if((h2===b1)&&((b1**2)===(a1**2)+(c1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is right!');
}else if((h2 === b1)&&((b1**2)<(a1**2)+(c1**2))&&((b1 === c1)&&(a1 === b1))&&(a1===c1)){
    alert('The triangle is equilateral!');
}else if((h2 === b1)&&((b1**2)<(a1**2)+(c1**2))&&((b1 === c1)||(a1 === b1)||(a1===c1))){
    alert('The triangle is acute and isosceles!');
}else if((h2 === b1)&&((b1**2)<(a1**2)+(c1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is acute!');
}else if((h2 === b1)&&((b1**2)>(a1**2)+(b1**2))&&(a1===b1)){ 
    alert('The triangle is obtuse and isosceles!');  
}else if((h2 === b1)&&((b1**2)>(a1**2)+(b1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is obtuse!');
}else if((h2 === c1)&&((c1**2)>(a1**2)+(b1**2))&&(a1===b1)){
    alert('The triangle is obtuse and isosceles!');
}else if((h2 === c1)&&((c1**2)>(a1**2)+(b1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is obtuse!');
}else if((h2 === c1)&&((c1**2)===(a1**2)+(b1**2))&&(a1===b1)){ 
    alert('The triangle is right and isosceles!');  
}else if((h2===c1)&&((c1**2)===(a1**2)+(b1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is right!');
}else if((h2===c1)&&((c1**2)<(a1**2)+(b1**2))&&((a1==b1)||(b1===c1)||(a1===c1))){   
    alert(  'The triangle is acute and isosceles!')
}else if((h2===c1)&&((c1**2)<(a1**2)+(b1**2))){
    alert('The triangle is acute!');
}else{   
};
var triangle_perimeter = a1+b1+c1;
p = Number(triangle_perimeter);
alert('The perimeter of the triangle is: '+p);
var triangle_area = Math.sqrt((p/2)*((p/2)-a1)*((p/2)-b1)*((p/2)-c1));
A = Number(triangle_area);
alert('The area of the triangle is: '+ A);
```

Comment: Go trough the individual properties that the array can have and collect the adjectives into an array. No `if`/`else`. Then at the end, format the word array into the output.

Comment: Would you please explain me little bit more detailed?!

Comment: How much do you know about data structures already? It looks like you're going through a course that hasn't covered them yet, but only variables, math expressions and control flow.

Answer (score 1):

I combined my previous solution with solution suggested by Bankole Alex-Esan and result is the code with 47 lines significantly less than previous 73 lines by combining control flow and arrays. The code looks like this:

```
var flag = false;
while(!flag){
    var a = prompt('Enter side a of the triangle', a);
    var b = prompt('Enter side b of the triangle', b);
    var c = prompt('Enger side b of the triangle',c);
    a = Number(a);
    b = Number(b);
    c = Number(c);
    if((a>=b+c)||(b>=a+c)||(c>=a+b)){
        alert('The triangle is not valid!');
        continue;
    }else{
        alert('The triangle is valid!');
        break;
    }
}

const AngleTypes =  ['acute', 'obtuse','right'];
const lengthTypes = ['equilateral', 'iscosceles'];

const getTriangleAngleType = (a,b,c)=>{
    if(((a**2)>(b**2)+(c**2))||((b**2)>(a**2)+(c**2))||((c**2)>(a**2)+(b**2))){
        return AngleTypes[1];
    }else if(((a**2)===(b**2)+(c**2))||((b**2)===(a**2)+(c**2))||((c**2)===(a**2)+  (b**2))){
        return AngleTypes[2];
    }else{
        return AngleTypes[0];
    }
}

const getTriangleType = (a,b,c)=>{
    if((a===b)&&(b===c)&&(a===c)){
        return lengthTypes[0];
    }else if(((a===b)&&(a!==c))||((b===c)&&(b!==a))||((a===c)&&(a!==b))){
        return lengthTypes[1];
    }else{
        return  'regular';
    }
}

let AngleType = getTriangleAngleType(a, b, c);
let TriangleType = getTriangleType(a, b, c);
let P = a+b+c;
let A = Math.sqrt((P/2)*((P/2)-a)*((P/2)-b)*((P/2)-c))
console.log(`The triangle is ${AngleType} and ${TriangleType}!`); 
console.log(`The triangle perimeter is ${P}`);
console.log(`The triangle area is ${A}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of your code, It seems you have access to the DOM (methods like alert and prompt are Window methods). So I'm kind of wondering why use prompts and alerts when you can just use input fields, and output to the page. But that's okay.

To your question ***"Is it possible to achieve the same goal with fewer lines of code to rationalize the code writing process?!"***. The simple answer is **Yes - Most certainly**.

From your question, it seems your code takes in some inputs, does some comparisons, then returns results based on those comparisons.  What I'm offering here are some suggestions as to a cleaner way to achieve this (coz there's a probably a million ways you could go about things like this).

We have a limited number of possible triangle types, which are generally of 2 categories - So we can put those in arrays.

```js
const angleTypes = ['acute', 'obtuse', 'right'];
const lengthTypes = ['equilateral', 'iscosceles'];
```

We could then have functions to do some repetitive Tasks - here's some psuedocode

```js
const isValidTriangle = (a, b, c) => {
 // check if entered params are valid for a triangle
 // return true or false
}

const getTriangleLengthType = (a, b, c) => {
  // Compare sides to get the length type
  // return an index or -1 (or string of lengthTypes[index] if index > -1)
}

const getTriangleAngleType = (a, b, c) => {
  // Compare sides to get the angle type
  // return an index or -1 (or string of angleTypes[index] if index > -1)
}
```

And then we could output our result string using the functions inside template literals

```js
let angleType = getTriangleAngleType(a, b, c);
let lengthType = getTriangleLengthType(a, b, c);
alert(`The triangle is ${angleType} ${lengthType ? 'and '+ lengthType:''}`)
```

We could also shorten some of the syntax with ES6. For example

```js
// to display perimeter and area of the triangle
alert(`The perimeter of the triangle is: ${a + b + c}`);
alert(`The triange area is: ${Math.sqrt((p/2)*((p/2)-a1)*((p/2)-b1)*((p/2)-c1))}`)
```

These are just a few things you could do to make your code as *DRY* (*Don't Repeat Yourself*) as possible. Please bear with the pseudocode, I will update the answer with actual code in a bit. If you need a complete rewrite of the program I could offer that as well

Comment: I combine above your suggestion with my previous solution - Bankole Alex-Esan